# How to zoom to selected feature with QGIS Python Console

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, select

I want to select a feature by ID and zoom to it. I tried the following but the canvas doesn't change. Any ideas?

```
canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()
cLayer = canvas.currentLayer()
cLayer.select(51)
canvas.zoomToSelected()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

`canvas.zoomToSelected( cLayer )`

The zoomToSelected method accepts a layer as argument, see [QgsMapCanvas](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsMapCanvas.html#a4540bf00bfb127cd47c863dfd4d99c48).

However, I've noticed it should also work without argument. That's strange.

Comment: What (strange thing) have you done with your layer? Perhaps an on-the-fly projection or something? I'm just guessing.

Comment: I realised somehow the selection doesn't work. You are right, the zoom works either way.

Comment: Yeah, that was going to be my next question!